# Is upholstery on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags

A new question was posted [about upholstery](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141293/replace-polymer-stuffing-with-foam).  To me, this doesn't seem to be within the defined range of topics for the site.  I checked the [upholstery](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upholstery) tag, which contains no guidance, and there are currently 6 questions that deal with repair, cleaning, maintenance, and techniques for upholstery and upholstering.  Is this subject area considered on-topic?

Comment: That upholstery link is dead as is the tag. Have a wonderful summer!

Answer (score 3):

Upholstery is (almost) entirely used on furniture and other items that are not part of the house. This makes it decidedly off-topic here, as an arts & crafts type of question. Questions using the upholstery tag should be closed and/or retagged and the tag allowed to die.